# Issues Installing Phenotrex

Tags: python-3.x, installation-package, installation-path

So I'm trying to install a package called [phenotrex](https://github.com/LokiLuciferase/phenotrex) but I can't install the dependencies correctly.

a sample command I have tried to run is :

```
phenotrex compute-genotype --out Pse_aerug Pseudomonas_aeruginosa.fna
```

but it gives the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepnog.models.deepencoding'
```

Has anyone else had an issue installing deepnog modules? If so, how do you fix such an issue?